# Cell Phone Ports and IP Addresses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

Situation:  I'm using a tablet and an old cell phone with an android app called IP Webcam, as video surveillance cameras.  They both have different IP addresses and I can view them in my browser when connected to the same network at home.  I want to be able to forward the ports on my router to see both cameras (individually logging in per IP address is fine) when i am away from home.

The problem:
1.  Both devices are using port 8080
2.  I can't figure out how to change the ports used on the phone or tablet
3.  My router (Linksys E900) will let me forward the ONE port and ONE IP address, but when i try to add the second device with a different IP address, but the same PORT number, it won't let me do it.

How can i change the port on the app on an old tablet/cell phone running android?  Or how do i forward the same port on the router with two different IP address?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would the router know which address to use? All it receives is the port.

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question...It would be the IP address i have externally:  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080.  I need to change the port on one of the devices (I think), but i don't know how.

Comment: But Shirley you can forward, say, port public_ip:8080 to device1:8080 and public_ip:8081 to device2:8080?

Comment: Or, for sanity’s sake, use 8081 and 8082 on the router to forward to device1:8080 and device2:8080.

Answer (score 0):

Your devices have two different IP addresses, but the router, visible from external world has only single IP, so following `port forwarding` is allowed:

`router global IP`: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 to `device local IP`: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:8080

Now, in-order to form another such `port forwarding` you would need different port!.

`router global IP`: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081 to `device local IP`: yyy.yyy.yyy.zzzz:8080

Assuming this is the [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en)  app in your question - you can check the port configuration in the application.

[image] Give it a try!